# Double integral finding upper and lower limits

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, polar-coordinates

I'm working on this problem:

> Calculate $$ \iint_D x y^3 \ln(x^2+y^2) dx dy$$ where $D$ is $\{ (x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 :9 < x^2+y^2 < 49, (x,y)>0 \}$.

What I need help with is understanding how to determine the upper and lower limit of the integrals. And is it easier to calculate using polar coordinates?

Comment: Yes, polar coordinates is a good idea. Then the limits will be $r\in[3,7], \theta\in[0,\pi/2]$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transform into polar coordinates $(\rho,\theta)$:
$$x=\rho \cdot \cos{\theta}$$
$$y=\rho \cdot \sin{\theta}$$
$$\rho^2=x^2+y^2$$

Then the integrand will be:
$$x y^3 ln(x^2+y^2)=2 \rho ^4 \sin ^3(\theta ) \cos (\theta ) \log (\rho )$$

Now do the integration:

$$\int _0^{\frac{\pi }{2}}\int _3^72 \rho ^4 \sin ^3(\theta ) \cos (\theta ) \log (\rho )\cdot \rho d\rho d\theta=\frac{1}{36} (-58460-2187 \log (3)+352947 \log (7))$$